# SPFx Reactjs Cannot Read Properties of Undefined

Tags: reactjs, sharepoint, spfx

I am using React to develop with SPfx for SharePoint online and am trying to rebuild a past solution I made, so that I can utilize the property pane of sharepoint to edit the webpart. I am getting an error of:

**ERROR:
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'fileAbsoluteUrl')**

when trying to render the grid. However, using the Edge developer tools, I can see the array being initialized with the information from the Property Pane.

If anybody could help explain why the code is returning an undefined, I would greatly appreciate it. Or if you have experience using PnP with SPFx.

This is my .tsx code:

```
export default class GridLayout extends React.Component<IGridLayoutProps, {}> {
  public render(): React.ReactElement<IGridLayoutProps> {
      const {
      description,
      isDarkTheme,
      environmentMessage,
      hasTeamsContext,
      userDisplayName,
      gridItems
      } = this.props;

      let arr = [];
      arr.push(this.props.gridItems);

      let firstItem = arr.slice(0, 1);
      let firstRow = arr.slice(1, 6);
      let items = arr.slice(6);
      console.log(firstItem, firstRow, items);

      if (this.props.gridItems && this.props.gridItems.length > 0) {
          var gridFirstItem = firstItem.map(el => {
              <div className={`${styles.tile1}`}>
                  <div key={el.Title} className={`${styles.galleryframe1}`} style={{ backgroundColor: '#2f2f2f' }}>
                      <a href={el.Hyperlink ? el.Hyperlink : '#'}>
                          <img className={`${styles.galleryimg}`} src={el && el.length > 0 ? el.filePicker.fileAbsoluteUrl : ''} />
                      </a>
                  </div>
              </div>
          });
          console.log('first grid item good...')
          var gridFirstRow = firstRow.map(el => {
              <div className={`${styles.tile1}`}>
                  <div key={el.Title} className={`${styles.galleryframe1}`} style={{ backgroundColor: '#0069f8' }}>
                      <a href={el.Hyperlink ? el.Hyperlink : '#'}>
                          <img className={`${styles.galleryimg}`} src={el && el.length > 0 ? el.filePicker.fileAbsoluteUrl : ''} />
                      </a>
                  </div>
              </div>
          });
          console.log('first row good...')
          var restOfItems = items.map(el => {
              <div className={`${styles.tile}`}>
                  <div key={el.Title} className={`${styles.galleryframe}`} style={{ backgroundColor: '#e64856' }}>
                      <a href={el.Hyperlink ? el.Hyperlink : '#'}>
                          <img className={`${styles.galleryimg}`} src={el && el.length > 0 ? el.filePicker.fileAbsoluteUrl : ''} />
                      </a>
                  </div>
              </div>
          });
          console.log('grid good')
      } else {
          return (
              <div className={`${styles.label}`}>Use Property Pane Editor to Add Tiles.</div>
              )
      }

    return ( 

        <body>
            <div className={`${styles.footer}`} >Our Mission: Provide the fullest possible accounting for our missing personnel to their families and the nation.</div>
            {/* Renders the grid */}
            <div className={`${styles.grid}`}>
                {gridFirstItem}
                {gridFirstRow}
                {restOfItems}
            </div>
        </body>
                
    );
    }
}
```

This is the code involving the property pane and the array:

```
PropertyFieldCollectionData("gridItems", {
                  key: "gridItemsFieldId",
                  label: "Grid Data",
                  panelHeader: "Grid Data Panel",
                  manageBtnLabel: "Manage grid data",
                  value: this.properties.gridItems,
                  fields: [
                    {
                      id: "Title",
                      title: "Item Title",
                      type: CustomCollectionFieldType.string,
                      required: true,
                    },
                    {
                      id: "Description",
                      title: "Item Description",
                      type: CustomCollectionFieldType.string,
                    },
                    {
                      id: "Hyperlink",
                      title: "Link to Open",
                      type: CustomCollectionFieldType.url,
                      required: true,
                    },
                    {
                      id: "filePicker",
                      title: "Select File",
                      type: CustomCollectionFieldType.custom,
                      onCustomRender: (
                        field,
                        value,
                        onUpdate,
                        item,
                        itemId,
                        onError
                      ) => {
                        return React.createElement(FilePicker, {
                          context: this.context,
                          key: itemId,
                          buttonLabel: "Select File",
                          onChange: (filePickerResult: IFilePickerResult[]) => {
                            console.log('changing....', field);
                            onUpdate(field.id, filePickerResult[0]);
                            this.context.propertyPane.refresh();
                            this.render();            
                          },
                          onSave: (filePickerResult: IFilePickerResult[]) => {
                            console.log('saving....', field);
                            if (filePickerResult && filePickerResult.length > 0) {
                              console.log('filePickerResult && filePickerResult.length > 0');
                              if (filePickerResult[0].fileAbsoluteUrl == null) {
                                console.log('filePickerResult[0].fileAbsoluteUrl == null');
                                filePickerResult[0].downloadFileContent().then(async r => {
                                  let fileresult = await this.web.getFolderByServerRelativeUrl(`${this.context.pageContext.site.serverRelativeUrl}/SiteAssets/SitePages`).files.addUsingPath(filePickerResult[0].fileName, r, true);
                                  filePickerResult[0].fileAbsoluteUrl = `${this.context.pageContext.site.absoluteUrl}/SiteAssets/SitePages/${fileresult.data.Name}`;
                                  console.log('saving....', filePickerResult[0]);
                                  onUpdate(field.id, filePickerResult[0]);
                                  this.context.propertyPane.refresh();
                                  this.render();
                                });
                              } else {
                                console.log('saving....', filePickerResult[0]);
                                onUpdate(field.id, filePickerResult[0]);
                                this.context.propertyPane.refresh();
                                this.render();
                              }
                            }
                          },
                          hideLocalUploadTab: false,
                          hideLocalMultipleUploadTab: true,
                          hideLinkUploadTab: false,
                        });
                      },
                      required: false,
                    },
                  ],
                  disabled: false,
                },
```